# ExpenseClaims do not include any Receipts so how do I tie back to an Account?

Tags: xero-api

I am using the Xero API to download transaction to try and build a view of Cashflow. For this I need to be able to categorise the Amounts into their accounts.

For Invoices and Bank Transactions I use the AccountCode on the LineItems collection to work out what Account to allocate the Amount to. For ExpenseClaims the LineItems collection is held on one or more Receipts in the Receipts collection. I was intending to use this however when I run this against the Demo company I get 4 ExpenseClaims returned however their is not Receipts included.

If an ExpenseClaim doesn't always include receipts how would I work out which Account the ExpenseClaim was allocated to?

Answer (score 0):

Receipts on expense claims are only returned via the API if you retrieve an expense claim individually by its ID. Take a look at our documentation for expense claims here: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/expense-claims